# What game uses dice with sides powers of 2?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

I have one die. It has six sides marked 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 and 64. Does anyone know what game uses this?

Answer (score 25):

Backgammon uses a die like that; it's known as a [doubling cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backgammon#Doubling_cube).  It's used, when playing a multi-game match or for money, to track the current stakes of the game.  Note that in this capacity it's not really rolled as a die; it's just a cube with the necessary numbers on the faces.